# Is there any reason to restrict the Hermitian adjoint to linear operators?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

The Wikipedia page on the [Hermitian adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint) is inconsistent about whether that operation is only defined for linear *operators* on a *single* Hilbert space, or more generally for arbitrary linear *maps* between (not necessarily identical) Hilbert spaces. It seems to me that the concept works equally well for general linear maps, but there may be some subtle technicality that requires restricting to linear operators.

Is there any reason why it's mathematically necessary to restrict to linear operators? If not, then is there any reason why doing so is more natural, convenient, or useful?

Comment: You are totally correct, and indeed the adjoint of a linear transformation between different spaces is quite useful.  -1 for the Wikipedia article $\ddot \smile$

Comment: How would you begin to define the adjoint for a non-linear map between vector spaces?

Comment: @TedShifrin As I explain in my question, I am not proposing to generalize the "linear" part of "linear operator", but instead the "operator" part.

Comment: Since the adjoint is in fact defined for any linear map between inner product spaces, I guess I missed the point. Just look at any linear algebra or functional analysis text.

Comment: @TedShifrin I did - the Wikipedia page :-)